# Excel: Row search based on multiple column criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Let's say I have this:

```
Input1 Input2 Input3 Input4 Output1 Output2 Output3
  1      1      1      1      4       20      11
  1      12     7      14     18      11      8
  4      2      18     7      0       6       16
```

The input values form a unique key (like a composite primary key in SQL). So each input column could have repeated values, but the whole set can't repeat.

Then I have this for searching and displaying data:

```
Input1 Input2 Input3 Input4 Output1 Output2 Output3
  A      B      C      D       E       F       G
```

`A` to `D` are the cells that I could key in. Based on these 4, `E` to `G` would find the correct row and display the correct output values.

I've tried using `vlookup` as an array formula (CSE), but it is not giving me the correct answer. It is returning me the value on the last row that `Input1` matches (regardless if other matched). Anyone knows how I can achieve this?

#### Edit

This is the formula I tried for the cell in `E`:

```
{=VLOOKUP(I2:L2, A2:G4, 5)}
```

where `I2:L2` is the range with cells of values `A` to `D`, `A2:G4` is the whole set of original data.

The formula evaluates to `18` when the inputs are `1`,`1`,`1`,`1`, whereas this should match with the first row and evaluates to `4`.

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're trying to do, but it may help if you were to include what you tried that isn't giving you the correct answer.

Comment: @ashleedawg Updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If A:D make unique combinations then you can use SUMIFS like this in M2,

```
=SUMIFS(E:E, $A:$A, $I2, $B:$B, $J2, $C:$C, $K2, $D:$D, $L2)
```

Drag right and down.

If A:D do not make unique combinations then you require a multi-column lookup, probably with INDEX/AGGREGATE; you also need to know which four-column match you want to retrieve.

[image]